# Sensu remediation - restart failing monitored process

Tags: sensu

We are using sensu for monitoring of certain processes on remote servers where we have installed sensu clients.

Is there any way to initiate restart of monitored process when sensu get information it is failing. I have found some information online about remediation handler

http://thesoftjaguar.com/posts/2015/06/14/sensu-remediation/

http://dev.nuclearrooster.com/2013/07/27/remediation-with-sensu/

But this do not seems to work for me, remediation is never triggered:

Also there are two ruby scripts which should help with this but not sure which one to use:

https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-sensu/blob/master/bin/handler-sensu.rb

https://github.com/nstielau/sensu-community-plugins/blob/remediation/handlers/remediation/sensu.rb

UPDATE 20th April:

We use sensu enterprise. In meantime I manage to get remediator.rb script to be called, but it is not working properly, since it can’t read JSON response from client and there are following exceptions:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-04-20T03:06:41.733000-0700","level":"error","message":"handler output","handler":{"command":"/etc/sensu/plugins/remediator.rb","type":"pipe","timeout":10,"severities":["critical","warning","unknown"],"name":"remediator"},"event":{"id":"f38cd413-575a-46f6-8845-09d713a29815"},"output":["/opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:54:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:54:in `block in deep_merge'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:52:in `each'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:52:in `deep_merge'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:22:in `block in settings'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:22:in `each'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:22:in `reduce'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-plugin/utils.rb:22:in `settings'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:123:in `api_settings'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:131:in `api_request'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:179:in `stash_exists?'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in filter_silenced'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:33:in `block in catch'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:33:in `catch'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:106:in `timeout'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:190:in `block in filter_silenced'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:188:in `each'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:188:in `filter_silenced'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:36:in `filter'\n\tfrom /opt/sensu/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sensu-plugin-1.4.2/lib/sensu-handler.rb:80:in `block in <class:Handler>'\nwarning: event filtering in sensu-plugin is deprecated, see http:// bit.ly/sensu-plugin\n"]}
```

We used following script as `remediator.rb` 
https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-sensu/blob/master/bin/handler-sensu.rb

Check is performed properly and we get response from sensu client server, but looks like remediator.rb is failing to process it.

Here is configuration:

```
remediator.json
{
  "handlers": {
    "remediator": {
      "command": "/etc/sensu/plugins/remediator.rb",
      "type": "pipe",
      "timeout": 10,
      "severities": ["critical", "warning", "unknown"]
    }
  }
}
```

Made it as simple as possible for check purpose:

```
/etc/sensu/conf.d/checks
{
  "checks": {
    "seyren_check": {
      "command": "/opt/sensu/embedded/bin/ruby /etc/sensu/plugins/check-procs.rb -p unexisent_process",
      "interval": 30,
      "subscribers": ["trep"],
      "handlers": ["remediator","default","file"],
      "occurrences": 1,
      "refresh": 10,
      "remediation": {
        "first_remediation": {
          "occurrences": [1, 2],
          "severities": [1]
        },
        "medium_remediation": {
          "occurrences": ["3-10"],
          "severities": [1]
        },
        "heavy_remediation": {
          "occurrences": ["1+"],
          "severities": [2]
        }
      }
    },
    "first_remediation": {
      "command": "touch /etc/sensu/plugins/test_lr",
      "subscribers": ["my.machine.local"],
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "interval": 10,
      "publish": false
    },
    "medium_remediation": {
      "command": "touch /etc/sensu/plugins/test_mr",
      "subscribers": ["my.machine.local"],
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "interval": 10,
      "publish": false
    },
    "heavy_remediation": {
      "command": "touch /etc/sensu/plugins/test_hr",
      "subscribers": ["my.machine.local"],
      "handlers": ["default"],
      "interval": 10,
      "publish": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include any related configurations to help identify where the issue may lie? Despite Sensu being a somewhat simple system, there's a bit of wiring required to get remediation working and it's easy to make a mistake (I've also implemented the `remediation` handler you included).

Comment: Hi, I have updated more information in question. @vase can you tell me which sensu version you are using? because I am wandering are some functionalities `remediation` use deprecated.

Comment: This was quite a while ago and I'm going off of memory for the most part -- I was running somewhere around 0.18.X.

I believe your issue is the latter `first_remediation`, `medium_remediation`, and `heavy_remediation` fields are scoped incorrectly. They're scoped to the full `checks` object, but need to be scoped specific to the check that they apply to (in this case, they should be one level deeper), right alongside the `remediation` key within `seyren_check`.

Answer (score 0):

- We prefer here to use a CM tool called Ansible.
  Here is the handler and the basic idea:

#

```
 #! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'sensu-handler'
    require 'json'

    class Ansible < Sensu::Handler
  def handle
    ansible = settings['ansible']['command'] || 'ansible-playbook'
    playbook = settings['ansible']['playbook'] || nil
    extra_vars = JSON.generate(@event)

    unless @event['check']['ansible'].nil?
      playbook = @event['check']['ansible']['playbook'] || playbook
    end

    command = ansible.to_s playbook.to_s
    output = `#{command}`

    if $?.exitstatus > 0
      puts output
      exit 1
    else
      puts "SUCCESS: #{command}"
    end
  end
end
```

- Then you create, the handler config:

  {
      "handlers": {
          "ansible": {
              "type": "pipe",
              "command": "/etc/sensu/handlers/handler-ansible.rb"
          }
      }
  }

And the Settings for the remediation playbook:

```
cat conf.d/handler/config_ansible.json 
{
    "ansible": {
        "command": "/etc/sensu/scripts/provision",
        "playbook": " --tags checksum"
    }
}
```

- And in your check configuration, add the name of the remediation handler:

  ```
  { ...
  ```

  "handlers": ["email","ansible", "logstash"]
  ....
  }
- Where the command is here:

  ssh root@my_ansible_server.comp.com -o BatchMode=yes -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o ConnectTimeout=10 ansible-playbook -i /etc/ansible/generic.hosts /etc/ansible/remediation.yaml ${@}